# Printing chars and their ASCII-code in C

Tags: c, printf

How do I print a char and its equivalent ASCII value in C?

Comment: So far there seems to be no correct answer among the 12 answers. Many fail at limiting the values to the 0 to 127 range as ASCII is a 7 bit encoding, and so far none has solved the problem that the numerical value of a character in C doesn't have to be the *ASCII* value! The system/compiler could also be using something like EBCDIC encoding, then the numerical value of an 'a' would not be the ASCII value of an 'a' in C.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

This prints out all ASCII values:

```
int main()
{
    int i;
    i=0;
    do
    {
        printf("%d %c \n",i,i);
        i++;
    }
    while(i<=255);
    return 0;
}
```

and this prints out the ASCII value for a given character:

```
int main()
{
    int e;
    char ch;
    clrscr();
    printf("\n Enter a character : ");
    scanf("%c",&ch);
    e=ch;
    printf("\n The ASCII value of the character is : %d",e);
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your code prints the decimal value created by converting the char to an int. This may be the ascii code on some systems, but then again it may not.

Comment: Why the above program doesnt print ASCII characters from 127 to 160?

Comment: Pretty sure ASCII stops at 127

Comment: Isn't this undefined behavior?? using `%d` to print a `char`??

Comment: Sorry, -1 for `getch()`. Terrible example using this non standard funcion.

Comment: @user007: No. It is not possible to pass a `char` to a variadic function. Any integer type that is narrower than `int` will be converted to `int` or `unsigned int`. The only case that can cause trouble would be an unusual implementation where `CHAR_MAX` is not representative in a `signed int`, but would cause all sorts of trouble elsewhere.

Comment: Representa**ble**. ...but that would cause all sorts of trouble elsewhere as well.

Comment: First of all ASCII has **7** Bits from **0 to 128** (**0x0 to 0x7F**) after that its called **E**ASCII meaning **Extended**Ascii.that is of **8-Bits** and if you need to print **EASCII** then you need **UTF-8** encoding enabled from **Locale.h** header file.

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
char c = 'a'; // or whatever your character is
printf("%c %d", c, c);
```

The %c is the format string for a single character, and %d for a digit/integer. By casting the char to an integer, you'll get the ascii value.

Comment: You don't need to cast to `int`, since the standard type promotions will promote `c` into an `int` automatically.

Answer (score 1):

To print all the ascii values from 0 to 255 using while loop.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int a;
    a = 0;
    while (a <= 255)
    {
        printf("%d = %c\n", a, a);
        a++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: ASCII has 7 bits so **0 to 127** after thats is system defined **EASCII**.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing can be more simple than this

```
#include <stdio.h>  

int main()  
{  
    int i;  

    for( i=0 ; i<=255 ; i++ ) /*ASCII values ranges from 0-255*/  
    {  
        printf("ASCII value of character %c = %d\n", i, i);  
    }  

    return 0;  
}
```

Source: [program to print ASCII value of all characters](http://codeforwin.blogspot.in/2015/06/c-program-to-print-ascii-values-of-all-characters.html)

Answer (score 1):

```
#include<stdio.h>
 void main()
{
char a;
scanf("%c",&a);
printf("%d",a);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This reads a line of text from standard input and prints out the characters in the line and their ASCII codes:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void printChars(void)
{
    unsigned char   line[80+1];
    int             i;

    // Read a text line
    if (fgets(line, 80, stdin) == NULL)
        return;

    // Print the line chars
    for (i = 0;  line[i] != '\n';  i++)
    {
        int     ch;

        ch = line[i];
        printf("'%c' %3d 0x%02X\n", ch, ch, (unsigned)ch);
    }
}
```

Comment: `%X` expects an **unsigned** int.

Comment: @NisseEngström - Code corrected, for the truly pedantic. Yes, it's always a good idea to use `unsigned char[]` for text buffers.

Answer (score 0):

Chars within single quote ('XXXXXX'), when printed as decimal should output its ASCII value.

```
int main(){

    printf("D\n");
    printf("The ASCII of D is %d\n",'D');

    return 0;

}
```

Output:

```
% ./a.out
>> D
>> The ASCII of D is 68
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplest approach in printing ASCII values of a given alphabet.

Here is an example :

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    //we are printing the ASCII value of 'a'
    char a ='a'
    printf("%d",a)
    return 0;
}
```