# Printing maximum values of INT

Tags: c, int, long-long

I try to print the maximum value of `int` in a program.
Using the following code::

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>
int main(void) {
    printf("%d",INT_MAX);
    return 0;
}
```

The output I get is:: `2147483647`

But, when I change my `printf` statement to `printf("%lld",INT_MAX);` my output becomes `577732524332023807`. `INT_MAX` value is supposed to be inside the range of `long long int`, then why is it not able to convert `INT_MAX` into the correct number in `long long int`.

Thanks for any help in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`printf` is a variadic function, it doesn't know its argument types, it relies on recieving the correct hints in the format string.

You invoked undefined behaviour with `"%lld"`, because you haven't passed a `long long int`.

To fix it, you need to cast - then you'll see the correct result:

```
printf("%lld", (long long int) INT_MAX);
```

Enable compiler warnings? :)

Comment: Thank you so much.. :) and sir one more thing is `long int` and `int` same?? because i try printing `printf("%ld",LONG_MAX);` but it gives the same output as `printf("%d",INT_MAX);`but it gives the same output.. any reason?? :\

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/589575/what-does-the-c-standard-state-the-size-of-int-long-type-to-be

Comment: @user007: We say that such behaviour is implementation-defined. Try to compare `sizeof(int)` and `sizeof(long)`. These should have the same values (in number of bytes) for your compiler, but C standard only says that `sizeof(int) <= sizeof(long int)` and requires that `int` is at least 2 bytes and `long int` at least 4 bytes.

Comment: @GrzegorzSzpetkowski If they have the same size with a few compilers then what is the use of having 2 different data types if they can hold the same values?? Neither I guess we can perform any special functions on long int and not on int, as they both are numbers..

Comment: @user007: It's mainly because of portatibility between various implementations. Some may have 16-bit `int`, some 32-bit, etc.

Comment: Hi, I just encountered something related to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1472581/printing-chars-and-their-ascii-code-in-c Isn't this undefined behavior as well??? Using `%d` to print `char` ??? The first ans to this question.

Comment: @user007: nope. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/variadic_arguments "bool, char, short, and unscoped enumerations are converted to int or wider integer types as in integer promotion"

Answer (score 6):

`%lld` is incorrect specification for `int`. According to the standard, it is undefined behavior:

> **7.21.6.1 The `fprintf` function**
>
> ....
>
> If any argument is
>   not the correct type for the corresponding conversion specification, the behavior is
>   undefined.

---

> **7.21.6.3 The `printf` function**
>
> ....
>
> The **`printf`** function is equivalent to **`fprintf`** with the argument **`stdout`** interposed
>   before the arguments to **`printf`**.

Comment: If I write `printf("%lld",2);` will that be defined??

Comment: @user007 No. It is undefined. The format specification does not match the type.

Comment: Hi, I just encountered something related to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1472581/printing-chars-and-their-ascii-code-in-c Isn't this undefined behavior as well??? Using `%d` to print `char` ??? The first ans to this question.

Answer (score 5):

You push 4 bytes of data (int-length) onto the stack in the call to the function, then tell the function to consume 8 bytes from the call stack to print it. So your value is trailed by 4 bytes of garbage.

You can tell the compiler to check for this.