# How to convert each character in a character array to integer?

Tags: c, initialization, literals

I have tried the standard methods but still I get error in my answer.

My code:

```
int main() {   
   int val;
   char str[] = {'1', '45', '0'};

   val = str[1] - '0';

   printf("Int value = %d\n", val);

   return(0);
}
```

I am getting answer as `5` instead of `45`.

How do I solve this issue?

---

[update from [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38260105/how-to-convert-each-character-in-a-character-array-to-integer#comment63940750_38260195):]

I actually need to process an array of strings..suppose I want to convert octal numbers to decimal, and my input has to be in the form of an array of strings. I wish to convert these no.s to decimal : {45,17,100} For that I would, at first be requiring to extract each element and change it to integer. Could you plz suggest what would be the best way to do it?

Comment: `char` **is** and integer type. What is your problem, what do you want to accomplish?

Comment: `'45'` is a multi-character constant. See [this answer to another SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3684046/434551) for further info.

Comment: Have a look at what the compiler tells you, when compiling the code shown.

Answer (score 1):

> I actually need to process an array of strings

What you have defined here

```
  char str[] = {'1', '45', '0'};
```

is not an array of strings, but exactly *one* array of `char` with 3 elements. It is not even a C-"string", as this would require a trailing value of `0`. Note that the value of the character `'0'` isn't `0`, but, for example, for the ASCII character set it's `48`.

`'45'` is a multi-byte character literal, which in fact is an integer. The code above tries to initialise the 2nd element of the `char`-array `str` (`str[1]`, which is a `char`) using this very literal.

This does not work.

A `char` cannot (necessarily) hold the `int` value of this *multi*-byte character literal. In this case the initialisation of `str[1]` overflows, resulting in the unexpected value of `5`.

To see the issue try the following code:

```
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdio.h>


int main(void)
{
  char c_min = CHAR_MIN;
  char c_max = CHAR_MAX;
  unsigned char uc = '45';

  printf("'1'=%d\n", '1');
  printf("'45'=%d\n", '45');
  printf("'0'=%d\n", '0');

  printf("lowest possible value for char=%d\n", c_min);
  printf("highest possible value for char=%d\n", c_max);

  printf("'45' converted to an (unsigned) char=%u\n", uc);

  return 0;
}
```

The example above shows how the value of `45` gets truncated when being assigned to `char`.

Depending on the C implementation you use the conversion of `'45'` to a `char` might even invoke the infamous Undefined Behaviour. This is not good.

What you seem to be wanting is:

```
  #define ARRAY_SIZE_MAX 3

  char * str[ARRAY_SIZE_MAX] = {"1", "45", "0"}; /*. Mind the double quotes. */
```

This defines an array of 3 pointers to `char` , with each pointing to a C-"string".

Answer (score 1):

Here, you are getting 5 instead of 45 because st[1] = '5', this is because we have only ASCII value of 0 to 9 integers and 45 have no ASCII value. 
To store 45 in your string you have to declare multidimensional string.
for example:

```
char st[3][3]={'1', '45', '0'};
```

Here is the working code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
    int i,ans,j;
    char st[3][3]={{'1'}, {'4','5'},{'0'}};
    for(j=0;j<3;j++){
        for(i=0;st[j][i]>=48 && st[j][i]<=57;i++){
            ans=st[j][i]-'0';
            printf("%d",ans);
        }
        printf("\n");
     }
     return 0;
}
```

## Output is

```
1
45  
0
```

Comment: To make your code fully portable, that is independent from the ASCII character set, you want to change the two Magic Numbers `48` to `'0'` and `57` to `'9'`.

Answer (score -1):

It depends, what do you want.

> Every character has it's own int value- It's simply ASCII code

If you will iterate over integers and make it print like %c you will get ASCII table (you can see it eg. [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1472581/printing-chars-and-their-ascii-code-in-c).

But if you want to read int values from string / char datatype you will have to parse it- ***atoi*** (ascii to integer) **function**- example [there](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_atoi.htm)

Btw I dont know how exactly your example works but the problem is you are doing following:    `int val = '45' - '0';` int value of '0' should be 48, '45' rly I dont know, but '4' is 52int and '5' is  53 int, so something like that..

As i wrote you should to do something like `int val = atoi('45') - atoi('0')` just for sure maybe better to cast into int as follows `int val = (int) (atoi('45') - atoi('0'))` - exactly asi in your example

```
int main() {   
   int val;
   char str[] = {'1', '45', '0'};

   val = (int) (atoi(str[1]) - atoi('0'));

   printf("Int value = %d\n", val);

   return(0);
}
```

Not sure, but i think that should works, hope that will help

Comment: `atoi()` takes either a `char`-array or a `char`-pointer, but does not take a `char`, nor an `int`. `str[1]` is a `char` and `'0'` is `char` literal, which is of type `int`.