# Printing ascii chart

Tags: c++, c, ascii

I was trying to print complete ASCII chart . Meanwhile I saw this code on [tutorialsschool.com](http://tutorialsschool.com/c-programming/c-ascii-chart.php) website .

```
#include<stdio.h>
void main() {
int i;
for(i=0;i<=255;i++){
    printf("%d->%c\n",i,i);
}
}
```

It looks perfect, but the problem is that it is not printing symbols for locations (I'm using Code::Blocks IDE) such as 7,8,9,10 and 32. I am really confused why it not printing values at those locations.And it is giving some weird output on online compilers.Is it the problem of Code::Blocks. What possibly could be the other program to print these ASCII symbols.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Printing chars and their ASCII-code in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1472581/printing-chars-and-their-ascii-code-in-c)

Comment: [man isprint](https://linux.die.net/man/3/isprint)

Comment: 32 is the space character, 9 is tab, etc.
You can at least try '%c' too see some more.

Comment: The group 0 to 31 in the ASCII table is known as "the non-printable characters". Your question is therefore why your program isn't printing the non-printable characters. Number 32 is space, are you sure it isn't printed?

Comment: Welcome to the world of misinformation on character encodings. The link you give shows a table that is not ASCII. It looks like CP437.  In C or C++, see the locale functions for the character encoding your program is using. To see the encoding your terminal (console) is using, go `locale` (Linux) or `chcp` (Windows). Neither are likely to be ASCII. If your IDE is showing output in a non-console window, that might have a different setting that is controlled through the IDE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might be interested in knowing that not all the ASCII characters are *printable*.

For example, decimal 0 to 31 are non-printable ASCII values.

See [this reference](http://www.ascii-code.com/), which mentions the same.

That said, for a hosted environment, the expected signature of `main()` is `int main(void)`, at least.

Comment: _All_ ASCII characters are _not printable?_

Comment: Yes, all are not, some are.

Answer (score 6):

> I am really confused why it not printing values at those locations.

Because those code is non-printable ASCII code. Note standard ASCII code has only 7 bit (ie 128 characters) - and several of them non-printable (control codes) - so you are not expected to be able print them (eg, can you print the Bell 0x07 ?)

http://www.asciitable.com/

---

And as Mohit Jain pointed out, you really need to use `isprint` function to check if a character is printable on standard C locale before printing it out - very handy function.

Answer (score 2):

Only a subset of [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) characters are printable.  Some are [control characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#Control_characters) such as line-feed, bell, etc..

Detail: ASCII is defined for codes 0 to 127.  Loop only needs `for(i=0;i<=127;i++)` for a *complete ASCII chart*.

--

[OTOH](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/OTOH), perhaps one wants to print a complete chart of all `char`.  When `char` are printed, they are converted to `unsigned char` first. So let us create a chart of all `unsigned char`.

Note: Using ASCII for characters code 0 to 127 in *very* common, but not specified by C.

To determine if the `unsigned char` is *printable*, use the `isprint()` function.  For others, print an escape sequence.

```
#include<ctype.h>
#include<limits.h>
#include<stdio.h>

int main(void) {
  unsigned char i = 0;
  do {
    printf("%4d: ", i);
    if (isprint(i)) {
      printf("'%c'\n", i);
    } else {
      printf("'\\x%02X'\n", i);
    }
  } while (i++ < UCHAR_MAX);
  return 0;
}
```

Sample output

```
   0: '\x00'
   1: '\x01'
   ...
   7: '\x07'
   8: '\x08'
   9: '\x09'
  10: '\x0A'
  ...
  31: '\x1F'
  32: ' '
  33: '!'
  34: '"'
  ...
  65: 'A'
  66: 'B'
  67: 'C'
  ...
 126: '~'
 127: '\x7F'
 ...
 255: '\xFF'
```